# How can one generate a magnetic field of a specific intensity(in terms of flux)?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

Was wondering how to generate a static magnetic field of a fairly precise value(teslas) for my science class. It needs to be relatively precise. Thanks for the help you can offer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_coil

Comment: How would one go about changing the flux value of a Helmholtz coil's generated field?

Comment: Vary the current or radius.

Comment: Varying the number of turns would also work